# Is it possible to user NMANavigationManager in Offline Mode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, here-api

I already succeeded to download Map Packages, and it works well in offline mode. Is it possible to use turn-by-turn navigation using NMANavigationManager in offline mode? I wanna provide voice and visual instructions in offline mode.

Sample code download Map Packages: https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/tree/master/map-downloader-ios-swift

Sample code turn-by-turn navigation: https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation-ios-swift

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can always download maps and voice packages for offline routing, navigation, etc.

A similar question was answered in this thread:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040853/in-here-api-how-do-we-show-downloaded-region-package-nmamaploader-in-mapview/56056319#56056319](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040853/in-here-api-how-do-we-show-downloaded-region-package-nmamaploader-in-mapview/56056319#56056319.)

Also please checkout this to see how to install/download voice packages.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-voice-instructions.html